# Xcode re-opening an app

Tags: ios, xcode, background, multitasking, foreground

What method is called if I start my app, press the home button and then start the app again/switch to it by doublepressing the home button and selecting it? It is not any of the following as they do not print anything when I re-enter the app:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
```

No other methods on [this site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) look like they are called when I change to the app, except for trying to add this piece of code but that didn't help;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {
    return false;
}
```

It feels like an extremely easy task but I've been testing all possible methods for 3 hours now. What method is called when I re-enter my application after opening it?

Edit: This has been resolved now, if anyone else is having problems of the same sort this image is super helpful. I found it after resolving my issue: http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/Bildschirmfoto-2012-03-05-um-5.26.29-PM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method will be called, and after that

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method will be called after you open the application from the background thread.

Comment: Well, they aren't. At least now I know they are supposed to be called so I can look somewhere else for the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm NSLog:ing to no avail. I know others have had problems with these methods not launching and it seems to be a problem with delegates for most. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Absolutely! Give me 15 minutes!

Comment: Ah yes of course. The AppDelegate calls these methods, it's from there I can do stuff. This was in another class, it doesn't call that method for all subclasses silly me X)

Comment: Can you please correct my answer if it was helpful to you... Thanks in advance... I m giving you +1

Comment: No no your answer helped point me in the right direction. Thanks again! The problem was not that I used the wrong methods, but in the wrong place.